# error when using Promise.all: TypeError: intermediate value is not iterable at

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to stop a list of sql instances, since it's async I am using `Promise.all` 
the code fails on:

```
TypeError: (intermediate value) is not iterable
    at Promise.all.sqlInstancesList.map (/workspace/index.js:40:53)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

what am I doing wrong? 
here is the code:

```
const { google } = require('googleapis')
const { auth } = require('google-auth-library')
const sqladmin = google.sqladmin('v1beta4')
​

exports.stopSqlInstance = async (event, context, callback) => {
        try {
​
                const authRes = await auth.getApplicationDefault()
​
                var sqlInstancesList = ["my-instance-name"];
​
                await Promise.all(
                        sqlInstancesList.map(async (instance) => {
                                console.info("stopping " + instance);
                                var request = {
                                        auth: authRes.credential,
                                        project: "my-project-id",
                                        instance: instance,
                                        requestBody: {
                                                 "settings": {
                                                          "activationPolicy": "NEVER"
                                                 }
                                         }  
                                }       
                                const [operation] = await sqladmin.instances.patch(request);
                                // Operation pending
                                return operation.promise();
                         })
                 );
​
                // Operation complete. Instance successfully stopped.
                const message = `Successfully stopped instance(s)`;
                console.log(message);
                callback(null, message);
​
        } catch(err) {
                console.error(err);
                callback(err);
        }

}
```

Comment: Is `var sqlInstancesList = ["my-instance-name"];` your actual code?

Comment: yes, this is for debugging purpose, after I manage to get this work, I will get the list of instances from the input (list contain one or more)

Comment: If you're debugging anyway, please try logging/inspecting the result of the `sqlInstancesList.map(…)` call.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried  return operation  instead of operation.promise() ?

```
const [operation] = await sqladmin.instances.patch(request);
                                // Operation pending
 return operation  // instead of operation.promise()
```

Because if you are awaiting you don't need to return promise() again